# How to store things in a set in PHP?

Tags: php

How do I write code such that I can put things in a set and only the unique entries are kept?

```
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
  $variable->put($some_object)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SplObjectStorage](http://www.php.net/splobjectstorage)

```
$s = new SplObjectStorage();
$s->attach($some_object);
$s->attach($some_other_object);
```

Note that you can also use arrays, the keys are unique and reassigning a new value to existing key overwrites the new one. But with arrays you have come up with your own ID-s, with SplObjectStorage you don't.

Array example

```
$a = array();
$a['key1'] = $some_object;
$a['key1'] = $some_other_object;
```

In the above example only 'key1' is kept.

Comment: Very true, SplObjectStorage does not work with plain old strings, you would have to wrap them somehow. Or just us an array for strings :)